# How to select datalist's description

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-datalist

I have 2 inputs in a form. In the 1st input, I load a `datalist` through `JSON`. The json list has 2 attributes `machine` and `lot`.

What I want is when the user select a machine, the 2nd input to be filled automatically with the lot. For example If I select `1` the second input to be filled with `lot1`.

An another approach is to select `data-description` element. But neither I don't know how..

```js
var dataList = document.getElementById('lots');

var jsonOptions = [{
  "machine": 1,
  "lot": "lot1"
}, {
  "machine": 2,
  "lot": "lot2"
}];

// Loop over the JSON array.
jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  
  option.value = item.machine;
  option.text = item.lot;
  option.setAttribute('data-description', item.lot);
  dataList.appendChild(option);
});

$(function() {
  $('#machine').on('change keyup', function() {
     var i = this.value;
     
     $('#lot').val(i);
   

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="text" id="machine" list="lots" class="form-control" name="machine" />
    <datalist id="lots"></datalist>
  </div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="text" id="lot" class="form-control" name="lot" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The actual code I use to load JSON is this:

```
var dataList = document.getElementById('lots');
var input = document.getElementById('machine');
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onreadystatechange = function(response) {
  if (request.readyState === 4) {
    if (request.status === 200) {
      // Parse the JSON
      var jsonOptions = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

      // Loop over the JSON array.
      jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');

        option.value =item.machine;
        option.text = item.lot;
        option.setAttribute('data-description', item.lot);
        dataList.appendChild(option);
      });

      // Update the placeholder text.
      input.placeholder = "machine";
    } else {
      // An error occured :(
      input.placeholder = "error:(";
    }
  }
}; 

// Update the placeholder text.
input.placeholder = "Loading options...";

// Set up and make the request.
request.open('GET', 'lots.json', true);
request.send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parse through the JSON again to get the `lot`. See the following code.

And you don't need to set the `lot` as a `data` attribute.

```js
var dataList = document.getElementById('lots');

var jsonOptions = [{
  "machine": 1,
  "lot": "lot1"
}, {
  "machine": 2,
  "lot": "lot2"
}];

// Loop over the JSON array.
jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  
  option.value = item.machine;
  option.text = item.lot;
  dataList.appendChild(option);
});

$(function() {
  $('#machine').on('change keyup', function() {
     var i = this.value;
    var obj = jsonOptions.filter(function(obj){ return obj.machine === parseInt(i)})
     $('#lot').val(obj[0] ? obj[0].lot : '');
   

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="text" id="machine" list="lots" class="form-control" name="machine" />
    <datalist id="lots"></datalist>
  </div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="text" id="lot" class="form-control" name="lot" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonOptions is not defined`. I added in the question how exactly i load the JSON

Comment: @yaylitzis Did you try my snippet? It's working fine!

Comment: @yaylitzis Move my entire code into the `request.onreadystatechange` function. Then it will work

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
  $('#machine').on('change keyup', function() {
     var i = this.value;
    var value ="";
//fetch from the existing options
     jsonOptions.forEach(function(a){
       if(a.machine == i){
         value = a.lot;
       }
     });
     $('#lot').val(value);
  });
});
```